# What is the proper way to call methods from a decorator where the method doesn't modify the functionality?

Tags: php, unit-testing, decorator

From this example, is CoffeeWithCream's getBrand() method improper or problematic in any way? My reason for doing it this way is to avoid writing $coffeeWithCream->$coffee->getBrand() everywhere it's called.

Particularly, one area of concern that's surfaced is unit testing. I'm not comfortable enough yet with Unit Testing to know whether this strategy complicates testing.

Also, I know that getBrand() is just a simple accessor method. What if the method performed a more complex task, would the answer change?

```
Class Coffee {
    public $brand;
    public $ingredients = array('coffee');

    public function getBrand() {
        return $this->brand;
    }

    public function getIngredients() {
        return $this->ingredients;
    }
}

Class CoffeeWithCream {
    public $coffee;

    public __construct(Coffee $coffee) {
        $this->coffee = $coffee;
    }

    public function getIngredients() {
        $ingredients = $this->coffee->getIngredients();
        $ingredients[] = 'cream';
        return $ingredients;
    }

    public function getBrand() {
        $this->coffee->getBrand();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that unit testing wouldn't be that more complicated since you are able to (and should) inject a mocked version of `Coffee` and test if the method `Coffee::getBrand()` is called when one calls `CoffeeWithCream::getBrand()`. The other way around, when you test `Coffee::getBrand()`, just test if the behaviour of this specific method is correct, what you would have done anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement an abstract decorator class, that uses the same interface like the coffee class. This abstract class is basicly used to pass all your method calls to the Coffee class. Your concrete decorators extend from the abstract decorator and only override specific methods, to which they want to add functionality. Please refer to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
With this you'll get rid of your $coffeeWithCream->$coffee->getBrand() problem.

```
interface ICoffee 
{
    public function getBrand();

    public function getIngredients();
}


class Coffee implements ICoffee { ... }


abstract class CoffeeDecorator implements ICoffee
{

    protected $coffee;      

    public function __construct(Coffee $coffee)
    {
        $this->coffee = $coffee;
    }

    public function getBrand()
    {
        return $this->coffee->getBrand();
    }

    public function getIngredients()
    {
        return $this->coffee->getIngredients();
    }  

}


class CoffeeWithCream extends CoffeeDecorator
{

    public function getIngredients() 
    {
        $ingredients = parent::getIngredients();
        $ingredients[] = 'cream';
        return $ingredients;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Seth for clarification. Did a read at your reference link and understood your answer. Award of 50 rep will be sent within 2 hours. Thanks again!